# How to clear the console in Darwin/Mac

Tags: macos, go, terminal, console, darwin

Trying to figure out how to clear console with Go in Darwin/Mac OS

I've tried the following methods already:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("clear")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Run()
```

As well as goterm lib:

```golang
goterm.Clear()
```

Neither of these work.  There has to be some way to do this, doesn't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `exec.Command("clear")` method is working on Mac. I'm running my test program using the command `go run ./...` in terminal. And tried `go build ./...` and then run the binary file, both are worked.

Test environment:

- Mac(Mojave 10.14.5)
- terminal
- bash: /bin/zsh

```
cmd := exec.Command("clear")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Run()
```

Comment: yeah I was running in Goland IDE and it wasn't working, it does work in Terminal though.